# How to use variables while calling pybedtools

Tags: bedtools, pybedtools

I am trying to use bedtools and fetch sequences from a whole genome fasta file inside the script I get region coordinates as variables.
For example:

```
chr_ = "chr1"
start = 3000
end = 3402
```

I am not sure how to wrap my function, because the example provided by [BedTool.sequence](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/autodocs/pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.sequence.html#pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.sequence) only uses coordinates in a string form.

Can you please help me to have something like this?

```
a = pybedtools.BedTool(chr_, start, end, from_variables=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to take your variables and make them into a single string variable.

for example:

```
chr_ = "chr1"
start = 3000
end = 3402
as_str = ' '.join([chr_, str(start), str(end)])
# or 
as_str2 = "{} {} {}".format(chr_, start, end)
```

Once you have the string built you can use the example in the [bedTool docs](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/autodocs/pybedtools.bedtool.BedTool.html).

```
a = BedTool(as_str, from_string=True)
```

Comment: If you like an answer please accept it so future users know it worked.